# How to assign a certain parameter of a csv file with certain conditions

Tags: csv, awk

I'm having a blonde moment.

How can I assign to a variable the *10*th parameter in a csv file.

For example, if I have this data as the last four lines in `mycsvfile.csv` among a heap of others on top...:

```
1432013000,m,NL,ABC,007,d,SVlts,675,1231537,24912,29017,24855
1432014000,m,NL,ABC,007,d,status,675,1243000,3570,-33.836465,151.051189
1432013632,m,NL,MSV,001,d,SVlts,675,631475,26979,29275,26462
1432013638,m,NL,MSV,001,d,status,675,638000,35770,-33.836465,151.051189
1432014232,m,NL,MSV,001,d,SVlts,675,1231537,24912,29017,24855
1432014243,m,NL,MSV,001,d,status,675,1243000,35780,-33.836465,151.051189
```

...and I want to access the *last* line where 4th and 5th parameter equates to MSV and 001, respectively, with the 'status' as the  7th parameter, how can I assign the 10th parameter (in this case 35780 to a variable called my_var?

would it be something like this:

```
my_var=`awk -F, "$4 == MSV && $5 == 001 && $7 == status" {print $10} | /directory/mycsvfile.csv tail -1`
```

And similarly for ABC 007

```
my_var=`awk -F, "$4 == ABC && $5 == 007 && $7 == status" {print $10} | /directory/mycsvfile.csv tail -1`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

```
$ awk -F, '$4=="MSV" && $5=="001" && $7=="status" {v=$10} END {print v}' file
35780
```

Or to store into a var:

```
$ my_var=$(awk -F, '$4=="MSV" && $5=="001" && $7=="status" {v=$10} END {print v}' file)
$ echo "$my_var"
35780
```

This keeps storing the 10th field when it matches the conditions. It will then print the last one, since it is always overriden.

If the file is quite big, you can also print backwards with `tac` and use `print; exit`, so that no further processing of the file is done:

```
tac file | awk -F, '$4=="MSV" && $5=="001" && $7=="status" {print $10; exit}'
```

---

Note the syntax I used, whereas you were saying `"$4 == MSV && $5 == 001 && $7 == status" {print $10}`. In general, use `awk '...'` syntax and double quote string comparisons.

Comment: thanks, but just to reconfirm awk searches the file from the last line to the first right? So if I were to change MSV 001 with say ABC 007 it would find the last record of ABC 007?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What my current answer is printing is the 10th field of the last line matching the specified conditions.

Comment: Yes the file is relatively big in size, by big I mean about 40,000 lines, how would I implement `tac` alongside with `print` and `exit`? Sorry for the trivial questions, but I sincerely appreciate your help!

Comment: @3kstc no problem! I just expanded my answer explaining how to do this `tac | awk` thingy.

Comment: last question: if I assign name=MSV and number=001, how can I fuse that inside the awk? `tac file | awk -F, '$4=="$name" && $5=="$number" && $7=="status" {print $10; exit}'`

Comment: You need to pass the variable with `-v`: `tac file | awk -F, -v var1="$name" -v var2="$number" '$4==var1 && $5==var2 && $7=="status" {print $10; exit}'`. Try to do some research before asking, because this is a very common question and easy to find.